# Reduce image size before store to the server using Storage function

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, storage

I would like to reduce the size of the image before saving it in the storage folder

Below is the code of my function
thank you for your support

```
public static function pre_update($Model, $data, $id)
     {
         $m = $Model::find($id);
         if ($m) {
             $field = $m->getFillable();
             $name = explode("App\\", $Model)[1];
             foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                 if (in_array($key, $field)) {
                     if (in_array($key, $m->getFiles())) {
                         $fop =$m->getOriginal()[$key];
                         if (Storage::has($fop))
                             Storage::delete($fop);

                         $image = $value;
                         $fpath = "img/" . strtolower($name) . "/" . uniqid() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                         $m->$key = $fpath;
                         Storage::put($fpath, File::get($image));

                     } else {
                         $m->$key = $value;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return $m;
         } else {
             return null;
         }
     }
```

Comment: You could use this package will helps in your case: https://image.intervention.io/v2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library Imagine.
Install wia composer "composer require imagine/imagine"
It should look like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

public static function pre_update($Model, $data, $id)
     {
         $imagine = new Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
         $m = $Model::find($id);
         if ($m) {
             $field = $m->getFillable();
             $name = explode("App\\", $Model)[1];
             foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                 if (in_array($key, $field)) {
                     if (in_array($key, $m->getFiles())) {
                         $fop =$m->getOriginal()[$key];
                         if (Storage::has($fop))
                             Storage::delete($fop);

                         $image = $value;
                         $fpath = "img/" . strtolower($name) . "/" . uniqid() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                         $m->$key = $fpath;
                         $imagine->open($image)->resize(new Imagine\Image\Box(220, 220))->save($m->$key);

                     } else {
                         $m->$key = $value;
                     }
                 }
             }
             return $m;
         } else {
             return null;
         }
     }
```